# Intraday Auto Fibonnaci Retracement Issue

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I'm trying to make an intraday auto fibonnaci but some reason it keeps picking up the previous day when applied.

Also is there a way to only let it show up on the current session than showing history as well?

[Anyone got any clue how to fix this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgWI5.png)

```
//@version=5
indicator('Auto Fib Track', overlay=true)

h = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high)
l = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low)

fibext = input(1)
fib0 = l
fib1 = input(0.2360)
fib2 = input(0.382)
fib3 = input(0.50)
fib4 = input(0.618)
fib5 = input(0.786)
fib6 = h
range_1 = h - l

fib0plot = h - range_1 * fibext
fib1plot = range_1 * fib1 + l
fib2plot = range_1 * fib2 + l
fib3plot = range_1 * fib3 + l
fib4plot = range_1 * fib4 + l
fib5plot = range_1 * fib5 + l
fib6plot = range_1 * fibext + l

plot(fib0plot, color=color.new(color.gray, 0), linewidth=3, style=plot.style_line)
plot(fib1plot, color=color.new(color.gray, 0), linewidth=2, style=plot.style_line)
plot(fib2plot, color=color.new(color.gray, 0), linewidth=2, style=plot.style_line)
plot(fib3plot, color=color.new(color.orange, 0), linewidth=2, style=plot.style_line)
plot(fib4plot, color=color.new(color.orange, 0), linewidth=2, style=plot.style_line)
plot(fib5plot, color=color.new(color.gray, 0), linewidth=2, style=plot.style_line)
plot(fib6plot, color=color.new(color.gray, 0), linewidth=3, style=plot.style_line)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the `lookahead` argument of `request.security()` is set to `barmerge.lookahead_off` by default. So it returns data from the timeframe before it elapses. This is done to prevent looking into future when getting data from higher timeframes. Naturally, you cannot know the daily high price before the day ends. More information about this is [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html#understanding-lookahead).

You can keep track of the daily high and low yourself with a `var` and some simple logic. You don't really need the `security()` for that. Here is and example for the daily high price:

```
is_new_day = ta.change(time("D"))
var daily_high = high
daily_high := is_new_day ? high : (high >= daily_high) ? high : daily_high
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Do you know how to only make it show on the current session, I don't really care about history session. Just want it on current intraday. Thanks

Comment: You need to use a `line` for that and delete or move the old line when it is a new session.

Comment: thanks, finally did the VAR line, it worked! Do you know how to prevent it from extending to the right and only during the candle?

Comment: Please ask a new question for that.

Comment: Thanks, I have asked a new question, will make this one as complete